# Mock adwords API

Tags: java, guice, google-ads-api

I want to test my code that connects to the AdWords API, without making an actual call to Google (that costs money ;) ). Any idea how I can plug in a new implementation of TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface?

AdWords Client API is using Guice for dependency injection, but I'm not sure how I can get the hold of the Injector in order to modify it?!

If it helps, this is how I get the implementation of it now:

```java
AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
AdWordsSession session = AdwordsUtils.getSession();

TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface trafficEstimatorService =
    adWordsServices.get(session, TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface.class);
```

Comment: Rather than change the way guice is injecting, can you just test your methods by passing in your own implementation of TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface and recording what operations are run on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [test account](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts) for this purpose. Also, there will no longer be a [charge for using the AdWords API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet2) from the first of March 2013, but you should still continue to use a test account while developing your tool.

Comment: Much as this is useful info, the question specifically asks how to control Guice dependency injection so that google is *not* contacted. I presume for unit testing as opposed to integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject a test implementation (mock / stub) of the Google API objects into your test code. The Guice injection that Google uses internally is not relevant here.

You should make your code depend on `TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface` and inject it at runtime, rather than having your code fetch a `TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface` from the `AdWordsServices` factory. Then, in your unit tests, you can inject a mock or stub.

See for example "[Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)" by Martin Fowler.

How this will look in practice for you depends on what IoC container you are using to run your application. If you were using Spring Boot, this might look something like this:

```
// in src/main/java/MyService.java
// Your service code, i.e. the System Under Test in this discussion
@Service
class MyService {
  private final TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface googleService;

  @Autowired
  public MyService (TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface googleService) {
    this.googleService = googleService;
  }

  // The business logic code:
  public int calculateStuff() {
    googleService.doSomething();
  }
}

// in src/main/java/config/GoogleAdsProviders.java
// Your configuration code which provides the real Google API to your app
@Configuration
class GoogleAdsProviders {
  @Bean
  public TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface getTrafficEstimatorServiceInterface() {
    AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    AdWordsSession session = AdwordsUtils.getSession();

    return adWordsServices.get(session, TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface.class);
  }
}

// in src/test/java/MyServiceTest.java
// A test of MyService which uses a mock TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface
// This avoids calling the Google APIs at test time
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface mockGoogleService;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testCalculateStuff() {
       Mockito.when(mockGoogleService.doSomething()).thenReturn(42);

       assertThat(myService.calculateStuff()).isEqualTo(42);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean()
        public TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface getMockGoogleService() {
            return Mockito.mock(TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface.class);
        }
    }
}
```